# Update background color of views depending on status from API + user item click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, animator

I have the following requirement:

- Show various stocks in a RecyclerView (1 stock per row: stock title,
  date, stock price).
- The user can click on the stock price view, which changes the color
  of the stock price view from white to gray    and the stock is added
  to a watch list.
- Every 10 seconds the list is    updated via an API    call:

  - If the stock price increased, change    background color of the    stock
    price view to green.
  - If it decreased,    change the background to red.
  - If   nothing happened and the user has not clicked on    the stock before,
    the background of the view should be white.
  - If nothing happend    and the user has
    clicked on the stock before, the background should be gray.

I've used Android's DefaultItemAnimator to compare the payloads that DiffUtil is giving me in my RecyclerViewAdapter. Changing the colors is not a problem. However, I'm struggling with changing the background color back to gray/white if the price stayed the same. Is there an elegant way to do this with the DefaultItemAnimator?
I'm checking the payload here:

```
class MyAnimator : DefaultItemAnimator() {

override fun recordPreLayoutInformation(
        state: RecyclerView.State,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        changeFlags: Int,
        payloads: MutableList<Any>
    ): ItemHolderInfo {

       when (changeFlags) {
            FLAG_CHANGED -> { ... }
            
            else -> { ... }
     }

}
```

But my problem is that I cannot access the necessary information in the else branch of the when condition, which means my only option here is to reset all unchanged views back to white. How can I persist which stocks the user clicked on and show the background as gray?

Comment: Whatever data class your list contains should have fields for whether it's clicked and which color state it's currently showing. Your UI code can always look to the data class to see what it needs to do to match the data state.

Comment: Thanks, I already have a field that shows if it's been clicked. But if there was no change in the data, I cannot access the respective data class in the animator or the viewholder :/